# Run local dns-server that forwards dns querys to different dns nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-hosting

I would like to run my own local dns-server, that forwards only some dns-queries to special dns-servers and all others to the public google dns servers.

The database of the local DNS-Server should not cache the queries.

E.g.: all subdomains with *.go.com to 192.95.16.109 and all others to google dns

Comment: What OS are you looking to do this on? Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 6):

[DNSMasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) does this nicely.

It is a pretty light weight DNS server.

A config that looks like this might be close to what you want.

```
# go.com requests
server=/go.com/192.95.16.109
# all other requests
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been pretty happy with unbound for a similar setup.

It can be configured to disable caching so it can do what you are looking for:

www.unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html

You can configure *.go.com as a forward zone.

I would start here: https://calomel.org/unbound_dns.html

forward zone configuration:

```
name: <domain name>
          Name of the forward zone.

   forward-host: <domain name>
          Name  of  server  to forward to. Is itself resolved before it is
          used.

   forward-addr: <IP address>
          IP address of server to forward to. Can be IP 4 or IP 6.  To use
          a nondefault port for DNS communication append '@' with the port
          number.

   forward-first: <yes or no>
          If enabled, a query is attempted without the forward  clause  if
          it fails.  The data could not be retrieved and would have caused
          SERVFAIL because the servers  are  unreachable,  instead  it  is
          tried without this clause.  The default is no.
```